# Can i hard coded row data for Ag grid?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I want to define the ag-grid row data manually. Because i do not have a same data structure in my database for the same structure i want to display on the UI.

I want to massage the row data, let it show the way I want it to display:

```
this.columnDefs = [
  {headerName: 'Field Name', field: 'fieldName', valueFormatter: valueFormatter},
  {headerName: 'My Trade', field: 'myTrade', valueFormatter: valueFormatter},
  {headerName: 'Cpty Trade', field: 'cptyTrade', valueFormatter: valueFormatter}
];

if (this.LinkedTrade) {

  this.rowData = [
    {
      fieldName: 'Trade Date',
      myTrade: this.LinkedTrade[0].mlpTrade.tradeDate,
      cptyTrade: this.LinkedTrade[0].cptyTrade.tradeDate
    },
    {
      fieldName: 'Counter Party',
      myTrade: this.LinkedTrade[0].mlpTrade.counterparty.name,
      cptyTrade: this.LinkedTrade[0].cptyTrade.counterparty.name
    },
    {
      fieldName: 'Notional',
      myTrade: this.LinkedTrade[0].mlpTrade.notional,
      cptyTrade: this.LinkedTrade[0].cptyTrade.notional
    },
    {
      fieldName: 'Effective Date',
      myTrade: this.LinkedTrade[0].mlpTrade.effectiveDate,
      cptyTrade: this.LinkedTrade[0].cptyTrade.effectiveDate
    },
    {
      fieldName: 'Maturity Date',
      myTrade: this.LinkedTrade[0].mlpTrade.maturityDate,
      cptyTrade: this.LinkedTrade[0].cptyTrade.maturityDate
    },
    {
      fieldName: 'Action',
      myTrade: this.LinkedTrade[0].mlpTrade.action,
      cptyTrade: this.LinkedTrade[0].cptyTrade.action
    },
    {
      fieldName: 'Transaction Type',
      myTrade: this.LinkedTrade[0].mlpTrade.transactionType,
      cptyTrade: this.LinkedTrade[0].cptyTrade.transactionType
    },
    {
      fieldName: 'Clearing House',
      myTrade: this.LinkedTrade[0].mlpTrade.clearingHouse,
      cptyTrade: this.LinkedTrade[0].cptyTrade.clearingHouse
    }
  ];
}
```

Now the table is showing as blank... I do not know if this is the correct way to do it. LinkedTrade is the data source i parsed from a parent component.

The expected result is we have 3 columns Field Name, My Trade, Cpty Trade. and I want to manually fill up the data like below.

Could anyone help me with this?

```
<div class="pl-lg-3 pr-lg-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="w-100" *ngIf="LinkedTrade">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-auto pr-sm-1"><h4 class="text-secondary">Status:</h4></div>
            <div class="col-md-auto pr-sm-1"><h4 class="text-danger">{{LinkedTrade[0].status}}</h4></div>
          </div>
          <table width="50%">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="card" style="width: 15rem; height:5rem">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    MX FCN: <strong>{{LinkedTrade[0].mlpTrade.murexRootContract}}</strong>
                    <br>
                    <p class="text-muted">MX NB: <strong>{{LinkedTrade[0].mlpTrade.murexNb}}</strong></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card" style="width: 15rem; height:5rem">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="text-muted">KX Position Id: <strong>{{getKxPositionId()}}</strong>
                      <br>
                      KX Id: <strong>{{getKxEventId()}}</strong></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>

              <td>
                <div class="card" style="width: 15rem; height:5rem">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="text-muted">MW Trade Id: <strong>{{LinkedTrade[0].cptyTradeId.mwTradeId}}
                      :{{LinkedTrade[0].cptyTradeId.mwTradeVersion}}</strong></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <app-atlas-grid #tradeDetailsGrid
                      [rowData]="rowData"
                      [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
                      [floatingFilter]="false"
                      [enableFilterComponent]="false"
                      [pagination]="false"
                      style="height: 720px; width:100%;"
      ></app-atlas-grid>
      <br><br>
      <div class="col-auto">
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info pull-right" type="submit" (click)="closeTradeDetail()">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are missing important parts of your code, like where you create the data grid object. It would be easier if you made an MVP by forking one of the plunkr's on AG Grid website as it could be failing from any number of reasons not shown here (the code above looks ok to me).

Comment: @Dominic Hi Dominic, i have included the grid code.

Answer (score 0):

i resovled this byt putting this in a function 
private setGridColumns() {}

somehow it worked..